# Verbes de perception : sens rendu par infinitive et sens rendu par subordonnée correspondante introduite par « que » sans différence aucune ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, infinitif, subordonnées, verbes-de-perception

Considérons des phrases du type suivant, qui comprennent un verbe de perception dans la principale, laquelle est complétée soit par une infinitive soit par une subordonnée introduite par la conjonction « que ».

- J'entends l'oiseau chanter.
- J'entends que l'oiseau chante.

Il existerait une equivalence sémantique entre des phrases de ce type, en particulier les deux ci-dessus. On trouve cette assertion, ou quelque chose à cet effet, par example dans l'ouvrage suivant.

> [Grammaire du Français • Terminologie grammaticale](https://www.ac-paris.fr/portail/jcms/p2_2125483/livre-terminologie-grammaticale-web-1308526?details=true)
> (voir  p.62)

1/ Est-ce que ce point de vue est universel ?
2/ Sinon, quel serait ce point de vue qui diffère ?
3/ Quelle serait en termes qui ne comportent pas le verbe « entendre » l'interprétation commune des deux phrases si le point de vue de l'équivalence est universel ? Autrement quel est-il pour chacune d'elles selon un point de vue qui serait différent ?

Answer (score 4):

À noter ce n'est pas exactement ce que la section de la page 62 dit.

La **Subordonnée Infinitive** "l'oiseau chanter" et l'équivalent **syntaxique** d'un **Groupe Nominal** comme "le chant de l'oiseau".

Elle n'est que **parfois** plus ou moins équivalente à une subordonnée complétive comme "que l'oiseau chante"

Dans le cas des phrase "J'entend l'oiseau chanter", "J'entend que l'oiseau" je fait à titre personnel une très légère distinction sémantique. Il ajoute un nuance de justification, celui qui parle cherche à se justifier.

De façon générale, toujours à titre personnel, la forme complétive est un peu plus distante est un peu plus abstraite.

"Je sens que l'oiseau chante" vs "Je sens l'oiseau chanter"

Un exemple plus radical qui ne marche pas entièrement, car "imaginer" =/= "imaginer que"

"J'imagine l'oiseau chanter" vs "J'imagine que l'oiseau chante"

Comment: On trouve à la page 62 « J’entends l’oiseau chanter = J’entends que l’oiseau chante. » ; ma question ne s'arrête que sur les phrases de ce type-là, considérée sans différence sémantique. Je précise même par « entre des phrases de ce type, en particulier les deux ci-dessus ».  Leur formulation serait ambigüe,  « n'importe quelle proposition infinitive est parfois équivalente …» et « il existe parfois une proposition infinitive équivalente dans tous les contextes … » étant les deux interprétations. D'aprés vous la seule valide est la première donc. //    (1/2)

Comment: Ces idées de « distance », de notion « plus abstraite », pourraient peut-être rendues plus précises ; vous est-il possible de fournir des paraphrases qui mettraient ces idées en valeur ? (2/2)

Comment: Fautes d'orthographe à corriger dans votre réponse.